# Database generate jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

**UPDATE 2:**

For simpler scripts, you would use jquery live to work with dynamically created dom.  Is that what the problem is here?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried moving the ajax for `get_tab_frame.aspx` out of the `$("#tabs").tabs({` section, which gives strange results, i.e. it will just return the tab names unformatted without the tab contents.  Then clicking on these unformatting tabs, just open a new windows instead of showing the tab content.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

The following script works well, which simply creates 3 tabs and gets the content of each tab from `tabs.aspx` based on the query string `tab`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs({
                    ajaxOptions: {
                        success: function(){
                            $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
                                .find( ".portlet-header" )
                                    .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
                                    .end()
                                .find( ".portlet-content" );

                            $(".column").disableSelection();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .column { width: 170px; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px; }
            .portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
            .portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
            .portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
            .portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
            .ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
            .ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li class="tab" id="tab_1"><a href="tabs.aspx?tab=1">Default</a></li>
            <li class="tab" id="tab_2"><a href="tabs.aspx?tab=2">Reports</a></li>
            <li class="tab" id="tab_3"><a href="tabs.aspx?tab=3">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I am now trying to database generate the content of `id="tabs"` and use jquery to insert the generated html into the `id="tabs"` div tab using the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs({
                    ajaxOptions: {
                        success: function(){
                            $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
                                .find( ".portlet-header" )
                                    .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
                                    .end()
                                .find( ".portlet-content" );

                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'get_tab_frame.aspx?rand=' + Math.random(),
                                type: 'GET',
                                error: function(xhr, status, error)
                                {
                                    alert(status);
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                },
                                success: function(results) 
                                { 
                                    $("#tabs").empty().html(results);
                                }
                            });

                            $(".column").disableSelection();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .column { width: 170px; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px; }
            .portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
            .portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
            .portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
            .portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
            .ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
            .ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="tabs"> </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

This is not working for some reason.  I just get a blank screen even though `get_tab_frame.aspx` produces exactly the same html i.e.

```
<ul>
    <li class="tab" id="tab_1"><a href="tabs.aspx?tab=1">Default</a></li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab_2"><a href="tabs.aspx?tab=2">Reports</a></li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab_3"><a href="tabs.aspx?tab=3">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/3RpC8/

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you've called $("#tabs").tabs() before you have loaded the html into the div.

The .tabs() function converts the current content to tabs - and you have no content.  It does not automatically change the tabs when you change the content with ajax.

It might work if you call $("#tabs").tabs() after you have loaded the content.

Comment: I've tried moving the code around, but it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the dom being created dynamically?  For simpler scrips, you would use jquery live, does something like that need to be done here?